# Detectar si la entrada de un programa viene de otro mediante pipes - Java

Tags: java, pipe

Estoy usando tuberías desde la línea de comandos para conectar la salida de un **jar** con la entrada de otro:

```
java -jar proceso1 | java -jar proceso2
```

Abajo tengo el `proceso2`, que recibe de `proceso1` un string y usa el método `contarVocales` para devolver cuántas vocales aparecen en el texto pasado.

Hasta aquí funciona bien. El problema es si quiero ejecutar el `proceso2` por separado, sin esperar nada de `proceso1` ni usar tuberías, la idea sería que al ejecutarlo de manera independiente pidiese un texto por consola que sería el que se pasaría a `contarVocales()`. No sé cómo hacerlo y lo que he probado no ha funcionado.

Código:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lineaTeclado = null;

    try {
        while ((lineaTeclado = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            contarVocales(lineaTeclado);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException n) {
        System.out.println("No ha introducido texto");
    } catch (IllegalStateException n) {
        System.out.println("Scanner está cerrado");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Se ha producido un error de E/S.");
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás algo confundido.

Es responsabilidad del Sistema Operativo proporcionar STDIN, STDOUT y STDERR a los procesos que lanza. De dónde provengan o adonde vayan esos streams es algo que el proceso no ve.

Dependerá del Sistema Operativo, pero por lo general si la entrada no viene de un `pipe` o no ejecutas el proceso en *background*, el SO ya te conectará la consola de donde lanzas el comando a STDIN, STDOUT y STDERR (o te creará una consola nueva si lanzas el proceso desde un GUI); no necesitas hacer nada especial.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Voy a investigar un poco sobre lo que me comentas. Pero sigo sin poder ejecutar ese código de manera independiente. Funciona bien si hago "java -jar proceso1 | java -jar proceso2" pero no si hago "java -jar proceso2".

Si lo ejecuto de manera independiente el proceso no termina nunca y nunca pasa al método contarVocales() el string que introduzco.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que pasa exactamente?

Comment: Voy a intentar sintetizarlo mejor, @SJuan76;

Desde la consola de windows escribo "java -jar proceso1 | java -jar proceso2". Proceso1 genera x String que se pasan por tubería a proceso2 (el código de arriba) la salida es, por ejemplo, "hola: 1 o, 1 a" y finaliza la ejecución.

Si ejecuto proceso2 de forma independiente lo que hace el programa es que imprime en pantalla el texto que introduzco y no cuenta los caracteres. Lo que quisiera poder hacer es que funcione bien ejecutando ese código de manera independiente. Imprimir un mensaje para el usuario pidiendo un texto y demás.

Comment: No te aparecerá ningún mensaje si tú no haces que tu programa lo muestre (`System.out.println`). Y si haces un `readLine`, el programa se quedará bloqueado hasta que introduzcas una línea por entrada (pulses INTRO para terminar la línea o cierres la entrada; normalmente es CTRL+D). Lo de que en la consola veas los carácteres que escribes también es lo normal; igual hay opciones para hacer que no los muestre al invocar al proceso(se le llama `ECHO`, si quieres investigar).

Comment: Gracias por el interés. En ese código he borrado el system.out.print porque está escrito para recibir el parámetro por tubería directamente desde el proceso1. No tendría sentido mostrar un mensaje al usuario pidiendo un texto por teclado cuando realmente no lo necesita porque el programa se ejecuta con un string que le pasa el primer proceso.

Comment: La cosa sería que el código funcionara tanto si recibe parámetros de un proceso que lo invoca usando las tuberías en línea de comandos como si se ejecuta directamente sin nadie que lo invoque. Algo así como "si no recibo parámetros de ningún otro proceso entonces se los pido al usuario '

Comment: No se puede. El proceso no sabe de donde le viene STDIN. Lo que puedes hacer es pasarle por parámetro al programa (en el `args[]`) algún valor para indicarle que no debe mostrar mensajes, y añadir la lógica. Al fin y al cabo, quien invoque el programa de una forma o la otra será quien sepa si hay `pipe` o no y si el programa debe mostrar mensaje o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @SJuan76. Me quedo entonces con que no se puede y las pruebas mil que he intentado al menos me han servido para aprender un poco más. Gracias de nuevo :)