# ¿Cómo saber si hay entrada de tubería en java?

Tags: java, pipe

Yo he hecho un programa que lee la tubería. Me refiero a esto...

```
echo "Hola" | java MiPrograma
```

A continuación el código

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadPipe {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
        String linea = null;
    
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // código a ejecutar
        }

    }

}
```

Pero cuando yo lo ejecuto sin la tubería...

```
java MiPrograma
```

el programa se queda esperando a que alguien ingrese algo.

Así que quiero comprobar (al iniciar el script) si hay entrada de una tubería o no.

Comment: Tu código debe funcionar correctamente. Puedes agregar como lo ejecutas? Si es con el comando que incluyes no hay problema.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Detectar si la entrada de un programa viene de otro mediante pipes - Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212648/detectar-si-la-entrada-de-un-programa-viene-de-otro-mediante-pipes-java)

Comment: Hola, el programa funciona bien. Lo que pasa es que si no uso la tubería, el programa queda estancado, esperando a que alguien ingrese por teclado, cosa que no quiero, lo que quiero es saber si se ha usado la tubería. Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del método [InputStream#available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) que te da un estimado del número de *bytes* que pueden leerse. Si te devuelve 0 te estaría indicando que no hay nada para leer y por tanto puedes asumir que no se han recibido datos por la entrada estándar (en este caso el *pipe*).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        if (System.in.available() > 0) {
            System.out.printf("Pipe detected...%n%n");

            java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String linea = null;

            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Piped param: " + linea);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No pipe detected :(");
        }
    }
```